# Changing the value of a single cell based on 2 different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-online

By using the IF function I am controlling the value of a cell based on the values of a different cell.
[image]

For example: If the date in Column G is bigger than TODAY() then the value of column N is "Not Started" otherwise the value will automatically change to "Pending".
Is there a way to use or combine another function or another method to not only keep the current IF formula but change the Column N value if the column H value changes as well??
For example: Now by still keeping the previous IF formula, if the column H value is not blank anymore, the N column value to change to "In Action" and if the H column is blank the N column to keep the original value based on the G column values.